# Change NSUserNotification shown time

Tags: c++, objective-c, macos, nsusernotificationcenter

I have NSUserNotification

```
NSUserNotification *n = [NSUserNotification new];
n.title = self.title;
n.subtitle = self.subtitle;
[NSUserNotificationCenter.defaultUserNotificationCenter deliverNotification:n];
```

But i cant control it banner showing time ? Is it possible to control it using some private api like

```
    [n setValue:@(self.ignoresDoNotDisturb) forKey:@"_ignoresDoNotDisturb"];
```

Comment: banner showing time - means how long shown banner 3 secs or 10